# how if condition works with multiple expression

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

My "if condition" look like below ,

```
if (expression1 || expression2) {
    // do something
} else {
   // do something
}
```

My question is, if expression1 get satisfied, then code flow goes to else part or expression2 get checked and then goes to else part.

Comment: what is the programming language? because the behavior depends on it.

Comment: @saamorim I'm using ObjC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most languages, including Objective C, **|| and && are short-circuit operators**. **As soon as no more of the arguments to those operators need to be checked, they are not**. So if expression1 is true, the whole expression:

```
if (expression1 || expression2)
```

evaluates to true for sure as:

`if(true OR X)`

is by definition true, and X's value therefore does not need to be checked. This short-circuiting behavior clearly depends on the first variable's value. If we have:

`if(false || X)`

we will have to check X's value to evaluate the whole expression. Similarly, if we have:

`if(true && X)`

we need to check X's value before we can decide whether the expression evaluates to true. However, if we have:

`if(false && X)`

we know that the whole expression will be false anyway, so X does not need to be checked - and in many languages, it won't be.

The above points are true even if X is a compound statement that itself consists of more than one variable. So in:

```
if (true || (expression2 || expression3))
```

the `(expression2 || expression3)` part does not need to be evaluated, as the whole statement will still be true regardless of what expression2 and expression3 evaluate to.

Comment: If the condition look like,  if (expression1 || (expression2 || expression3)) then second part get evaluated or not?

Comment: If expression1 evaluates to true, then the second part will not get checked.

Comment: You're welcome. Updated the answer to point out that case as well.

Answer (score 1):

If `expression1` is evaluated to `true` then `expression2` is not evaluated at all because the if expression will be `true` no matter what `expression2` is evaluated.

If `expression1` is evaluated to `false` then `expression2` is evaluated. If `expression2` is evaluated to `false` then `if` goes to `else` statement

You can think of it something like that:

```
if (expression1){
//execute_block_1
} else if(expression2){
//execute_block_1
}else{
//execute_block_2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a || $b   gives  TRUE if either $a or $b is TRUE.
```

Answer (score 0):

**||** is the sign of **OR** if any one variable have **true** value then it return **true**.

```
if(expression1 || expression 2)
```

It mean if one variable either expression1 or expression2  return a **true** value  then  whole condition be return a **true** value.

**&&** is the sign of **AND** if any one variable have **false** value then it return **false**.

```
if(expression1 && expression 2)
```

It mean if one variable either expression1 or expression2  return a **false** value  then  whole condition be return a **false** value.in this case if both variable are **true** then if condition return a **true** value